# In Redux-Observable must ofType be followed immediately by one of the map operators?

Tags: rxjs, redux-observable

I'm making an ajax request in the epic below but just before the mergeMap begins the call I would like to fire off the RESET_IMAGE action, however, the code below isn't achieving this. Is it possible or can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

```
const imageUploadEpic = (action$, state$) =>
  action$.pipe(
    ofType('UPLOAD_IMAGE'),
    mapTo('RESET_IMAGE'),
    mergeMap(action =>
      from(
        axios.post(`/uploads/url`, {
          url: action.src
        })
      ).pipe(
        map(response => ({
          type: 'UPLOAD_IMAGE_SUCCESS',
          data: response.data
        })),
        catchError(error =>
          of({
            type: 'UPLOAD_IMAGE_ERROR',
            error
          })
        )
      )
    )
  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `concat` to produce two actions like this:

```
const imageUploadEpic = (action$, state$) =>
  action$.pipe(
    ofType('UPLOAD_IMAGE'),
    mergeMap(action =>
      concat(
        of({ type: 'RESET_IMAGE' }),
        from(
          axios.post(`/uploads/url`, {
            url: action.src
          })
        ).pipe(
          map(response => ({
            type: 'UPLOAD_IMAGE_SUCCESS',
            data: response.data
          })),
          catchError(error =>
            of({
              type: 'UPLOAD_IMAGE_ERROR',
              error
            })
          )
        )
      )
    )
  );
```